# losing entire pointer information when passing object pointer as argument

Tags: c++, pointers, arguments

**I am trying to understand why passing a pointer as an argument would cause me to lose the entire pointer information inside a function.**

My question isn't that complicated I just provided ample amount of code to give you context, in case, you need. But I feel like this is a very elementary/basic problem

This is the class set up relevant to my problem

```
class node
{
        public:
        node();
        node( char n_type,int n_xcoordinate, int n_ycoordinate, int  n_elevation);
        node(const node & source);
        void  connect(node* connection);
        void copy_elements(node* ptr);
        ~node();
        void ndisplay();
        protected:
                int nxcoordinate;
                int nycoordinate;
                char  ntype;
                int  nelevation;
                node* next;
 };
class graph
{
        public:
                graph(); 
                graph(const graph & source);
                void  add( node * element);
                void connect_vertices(node* ptr1, node* ptr2);
//              ~graph(); 
                void g_display();
        protected: 
                node** adj_list;
                int count;
```

Essentially I am losing pointers when I pass them as arguments

So I set an array node pointers. And I point them the relevant nodes with this funtion. WORKS

```
void graph::add( node *  element)
{
   while(count < 3)
   {
         adj_list[count] = element;    
         count ++;
         break;   
   }
```

Then with this function I check if everything's in place, and it is. `ndisplay` which is a function of `node` class prints out the values of the object's elements.WORKS AND PRINTS EVERYTHING CORRECTLY

```
void graph::g_display()
{
     for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
      {
         adj_list[i]->ndisplay();

       }
}
```

But when I  call `adj_list[count]-> connect(adj_list[count-1]`,. I get seg fault inside the `connect` function, which is one of the `node` functions, because the object data members (of the node passed as argument) are empty (pointer is not pointing to the right place).

I tried to use a wrapper function to understand what is really going on,So when I call the below function as `connect_vertices(adj_list[count],adj_list[count-1])` and **realized as soon as I pass the pointers as an argument for a `node` function, they are gone.(a.k.a, pointer is not pointing to the right place?)**

```
void graph::connect_vertices(node*ptr1, node*ptr2)
{       
        ptr1->ndisplay(); //I get seg fault inside the ndisplay()
        //ptr1->connect(ptr2) This is what it's supposed to do
}
```

I thought passing pointers was kind of safe because you were passing memory address? Can you see/direct me to the root of my problem?

Comment: You're probably passing an invalid pointer around. Unfortunately that's mostly up to you to debug.

Comment: I smell undefined behavior

Comment: I would start with a debugger. Place some breakpoints in the various functions that are causing unexpected behaviour and see if the values of variables match what you expect

Comment: You only add **one** element to `adj_list` because `break;` terminates the loop immediately.

Comment: @Galik I actually call the add function for all the objects beforehand. They are definitely there when I try to call the other functions. When I call the g_display, I see right amount of objects.

Comment: Ah. I guess I would probably have used a `if` in that case.

Comment: [Edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: After `adj_list[count] = element;    count ++;` you have incremented `count` so `adj_list[count]` is now the next element, which has not been assigned. I suspect that you don't "lose pointers" but instead try to use one that has never been assigned.

Comment: It is impossible to say what's going wrong. You need to post a MCVE. (See Sid's comment.) The presence of  void connect_vertices(node* ptr1, node* ptr2); makes me think you are using raw pointers as owning-parameters. There be monsters. Avoid using pointers at all for now. Use standard containers from the STL, which hide and monitor the pointers as required. If you reeeeeealy want to use pointers, use std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr as appropriate.

Comment: @BoPersson Standing ovation for being able to see that in the middle of all these noise I provided.  One line swap, and all my problems are gone. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!